# Does C++17 (std::filesystem) provide the same error codes as Boost.Filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, error-handling, c++17, std-filesystem

I'm preparing code using Boost.Filesystem for (eventual) availability of std::filesystem in C++17 Xcode 10.x.  Is there a cross-platform method to avoid translating between those two libraries for common filesystem errors like:

> no_such_file_or_directory (which is the same as ENOENT)

I want to be able to smoothly transition to C++17 std::filesystem support in a cross-platform manner across MacOS, Windows, and linux.

(I saw other posters create their own table search methods for pre-C++17 (pre std::filesystem) compilers, but could it be more compatible since std::filesystem was based on Boost.Filesystem?)

SOME ADDITIONAL THOUGHTS:

I see that the C++ std::error_condition is a CLASS, which is noted as being "platform independent".  boost::system::error_condition is a similar class that is considered "generic".

But most of boost filesystem operations return a boost::system::error_code.

This article nicely explains the disconnect I was seeing between error_code and error_condition for the c++ std error classes.  I expect it will be the same for boost:

http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-2.html

Comment: Can you get any *guarantees*? - No. Will it *probably* work? - Yes. Should you rely on that? - No.

Comment: What does “more compatible” mean?  Even if the error codes will have the same names, that’s only *source* compatibility…

Comment: @DavisHerring - by "more compatible", I meant any cobbled-together approach attempted before the c++17 std::filesystem standard was finalized MIGHT no longer be necessary since it's 2019 and the standard has, for the most part, been implemented.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- I guess what I'm focusing on is: I suspect that C++11's std::errs enum of no_such_file_or_directory == POSIX ENOENT, and Boost.Filesystem's boost::system::errc::no_such_file_or_directory == POSIX ENOENT, so can I assume a Windows C++11 std::errs enum of no_such_file_or_directory MEANS "no such file or directory"?

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- part 2: of above comment: I want to use ONE C++ enum to represent the same error condition on multiple platforms .